# JS/jQuery – Check initial position once inside a loop (scroll event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global, local

**EDIT**

```
var setInitPos = true;

function loop() {

  $(".image").each(function() {
    // some other code

    if (imageIsVisible) {
      // some other code

      // Set variable initPos only once for each item
      if (setInitPos) {
        initPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        setInitPos = false;
      }
    }

    // some other code
  })

}

$(window).scroll(function(){ loop() }
```

If an item is visible within the viewport fill the var initPos once with a value for each item.

But now the second item starts with setInitPos = false! Why is that?

Comment: What local variable? `initPos` is not local inside of the each.

Comment: `initPos` inside the if condition.

Comment: Well local variables are declared with `var` inside the block, I see no `var`. Also having the same name for the variable with global and local is not going to result in what you want either.

Comment: @epascarello Hmm, any advice how I can write it differently?

Comment: @Ben You are not referring to local vs global variables - you are asking a question about persisting some data on DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

The best way to persist `initPos` on a per DOM-element basis is by attaching it to each DOM element, which you can do with `jQuery`'s `.data()`

```
  $(".image").each(function() {
    var initPos = $(this).data('initpos') || 0;

    // some other code

    if (imageIsVisible) {
      // some other code

      // Set variable initPos only once for each item
      if (!initPos) {
        $(this).data('initpos',$(window).scrollTop());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but everytime I scroll the initPos is set again. I only want to set it once.

Comment: You've confused people with your term `local variable` which is not what you are actually referring to. What you need to do is to store the value of the last position on each element, which you can do with `.data()`

Comment: Perfect answer @Adam — only **initPos** and **initpos** had to be spelled equally – then your code works just fine! Thanks!

Comment: @Ben - why do they have to be spelled equally for the code to work?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake @Adam. Your code as it is works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It's global, because you specified it in the global scope.

To make it local to the iteration, then declare it within the function. You need to use the varbkeyword for this (or let if you use ES6)

To make it local to the image, use this.initPos, this way you create a new attribute for each image element.

Comment: It’s inside a scroll event. Next time if scrolled it starts with 0 again and the variable is set again. It should only happen once.

Comment: @Ben You shpuld post the whole code neccessary to underdtand the question

Answer (score 0):

i found no other variable declared except initPos. And Its only declared once.

try to declare "var initPos" again inside "if (imageIsVisible) {"